# User inventory stacking SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2014

I want to stack items in users their inventory.

If you have a new weapon with the same `ItemID`, it just creates a new row like in the picture below.

[image: Table layout]

If the `ItemID` exists then it needs to change the quantity to the number of weapons you've actually got, and delete the duplicate rows.

What type of query is that, or help me on the way?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. What do you mean by "stack items in users their inventory"? It will create a new row because InventoryID is different (unique)

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with `qsqlquery`?

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems in your table design. First, I do not understand the purpose of `InventoryID` here. Because the `InventoryID` is unique (which I would assume to be the `primary key`, that's why every time when you have an additional `itemID` (same or not), it will be treated as a new row.

I do not know what you're trying to achieve in the end, but,

Option 1: Create a separate table `Inventory` with `InventoryID` and probably `ItemID` and `LeasedUntil`, then modify your current table to only `CustomerID` and `ItemID` and `quantity`

Option 2: keep your current table, add another table called `Item` that has only `ItemID` and `Quantity`

You may also want to review table `Normalization` here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878

Your current table is in 1NF